# opencv detect consecutively lines

Tags: opencv

Sorry I just started learning opencv for a couple of days, and I don't have enough reputation to post images directly. I am trying to detect lines on the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bXsg.jpg), and do some AR stuffs on it by following steps:

1. using Canny find edges
2. lineHough edges and find lines.
3. By the lines I get, I can display something on the wall by doing
   some perspective transformation calc.

But when I do cv::Canny, the result is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGWzT.png). 
And HoughLinesP gave me 18 lines based on that, but what I expected was 4.

Here's my code:

```c
+(UIImage *) detectLines: (UIImage *)img {
    cv::Mat src, dst, color_dst;
    src = [openUtil cvMatFromUIImage:img];
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;

//    cv::medianBlur(src, dst, 5);
    Canny( src, dst, 50, 200, 3 );
    cvtColor( dst, color_dst, CV_GRAY2BGR );

//    cv::HoughLinesP( dst, lines, 5, CV_PI/180, 60, 30, 20 );
//    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
//    {
//        line( src, cv::Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
//             cv::Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8 );
//    }

    return [openUtil UIImageFromMat:color_dst];
}
```

Any advice that I can do it in a better(proper) way??

Comment: What do you mean by "AR study"?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, AR stuff. It will be used in a mobile app. User should be able to open the camera, and make some mark on the image to record there is something unusual on the marked area. So next time when he come back, he can open the camera again, and the marks will show up on the right place he recorded.

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload the image which you are expecting as an input? If not, which lines do you expect to get from the main image?

Comment: @RickM. The input image is https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bXsg.jpg, and the Canny output image is https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGWzT.png.